# Quicksort algorithm not working, displays a 10 instead of a 4

Tags: c++

I am trying to use the quicksort algorithm to sort some binary files. I did a merge sort algorithm and was able to sort 10,000,000 numbers in 7 seconds. I am trying to see if quicksort will do it faster or not, however, I am having trouble getting my quicksort to work. It sorts the data correctly, however it takes a 4 from the binary file and converts it into a 10.

When I call quicksort I do: Quicksort(size, 1, arrayToSort);
- Size is the size of the binary list, so it is changing, I am testing 10 numbers, so it is 10 right now, and represents high, or h. I am using 1 for low, or l because I am starting at 1 base. I combined the partition and sorting functions to just be one big function. Any ideas will help, thanks.

```
void Quicksort(int h, int l, int *arrayToSort)
{
    int Pivot = arrayToSort[(l + h) / 2];
    arrayToSort[Pivot] = arrayToSort[l];
    int templ = l, temph = h;

    while (true)
    {
        while (arrayToSort[h] > Pivot && l < h)
        {
            h--;
        }
        if (l < h)
        {
            arrayToSort[l] = arrayToSort[h];
            l++;
        }
        else
        {
            arrayToSort[h] = Pivot;
            break;
        }
        while (arrayToSort[l] < Pivot && l < h)
        {
            l++;
        }
        if (l < h)
        {
            arrayToSort[h] = arrayToSort[l];
            h--;
        }
        else
        {
            arrayToSort[l] = Pivot;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (l - templ >= 2)
        Quicksort(h - 1, templ, arrayToSort);
    if (temph - h >= 2)
        Quicksort(temph, l + 1, arrayToSort);
}
```

Comment: if (l - templ >= 2)
  Quicksort(h - 1, templ, arrayToSort);
 if (temph - h >= 2)
  Quicksort(temph, l + 1, arrayToSort); should also be added at the bottom of the while loop, sorry missed it.

Comment: You may answer your own questions when you come up with the answer yourself. No need to limit it to a comment.

Comment: Why are you writing your own sort routine?

Comment: Unrelated: What you have implemented doesn't look much like a quicksort. If this is for school you may lose some marks even if it does successfully sort.

Answer (score 0):

The first bug is here, you overwrite the Pivot'th position instead of the Pivot's position.

```
arrayToSort[Pivot] = arrayToSort[l];
```